# Multiple functions at different times under a single setInterval(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a countdown timer that refreshes an image every 30 seconds. This code has been working well for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var countdown = 30;
jQuery('#countdown').html(countdown);
setInterval(function() {
    countdown--;
    jQuery('#countdown').html(countdown);
            if (countdown <= 0)
    {
        jQuery('.imagerefresh').attr('src', jQuery('.imagerefresh').attr('src'));
        countdown = 30;
        jQuery('#countdown').html(countdown);
            }
}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to add the code below to get a new image at the 10 second mark and save it locally on the server. When I add it to the code above (before line 7, "if (countdown <=0)"), it seems to get the new image and save it just fine at the 10 second mark, but on the image refresh at 0 seconds the image seems to refresh then immediately collapse on itself.

```
if (countdown <= 10)
{
     jQuery.get('/path/to/file/getnewimage.php');
}
```

Suggestions on how to fix the image collapse? Or suggestions on more efficient code to get the new image before refreshing it on the page. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't even wait until the 20th second of your countdown to get the image. I'd just right away preload it when you refresh your current image and just keep it in memory until it is needed the next time the countdown has run off. About the collapsing... any live demonstration you can offer to visualize the problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "collapse on itself", but regarding your method of adding the `?...` query string to the end of the URL, the second and subsequent times through the cycle you'll end up with additional question marks and timestamps on the end of the URL, i.e., the URL will be getting longer and longer.

Comment: @BZCS, did you find my answer useful?

Comment: wait, let me update it!

Comment: Still having issues with the update - seems to get stuck at countdown "0", makes one attempt at getting new image at countdown "0", but never refreshes image on page and doesn't want to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about **stop using setInterval** (http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=i_qE1iAmjFg#t=462s):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/2Jaqy/7/

```
$(function() {

    var max = 30;
    var countdown = max;
    var img = $('#image');
    var display = $('#countdown');

    img.load(function(event) {

        setTimeout(refresh, 1000);

    });

    var load = function(url) {

        var ts = (new Date()).getTime();
        img.attr('src', url + '?ts=' + ts);

    };

    var get = function() {

        //$.get('/path/to/file/getnewimage.php', load);
        setTimeout(function() {

            load('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');

        }, 500);

    };

    var refresh = function() {

        display.text('wait ' + countdown + ' seconds...');
        countdown--;

        if(countdown < 0) {

            countdown = max;
            get();

        } else {

            setTimeout(refresh, 1000);

        }

    };

    get();

});
```

and taking care about the image loading.

Comment: Thanks for the video link, very useful - but couldn't get the above code to work in my case.

Comment: I'm still having the problem of the image not showing on refresh ("collapsing" as I was referring to in the original code). I also will need to some how coordinate the image get code to the image display code because it currently seems to display before the image has had time to fully download (I see this currently on the initial page load).

Comment: you'll need to uncomment the $.get and remove the dummy timeout

Comment: Sorry, been testing and trying to get it work. Seems to get stuck at countdown "0", makes one attempt at getting new image at countdown "0", but never refreshes image on page and doesn't want to loop.